# python-telegram-bot 8 not seeing other bots messages

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I´m using python-telegram-bot 8 and my bot is not processing messages that are sent by other bots in a group

Works OK with other users (not bots)

why my bot, don't see other bots messages?

```
def main():

    updater = Updater(bot_token)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,check_msg))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.video | Filters.photo | Filters.document, check_file))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, check_sticker))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots), bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

The only exception is the channel, if your bot is an admin of channel, they can see any messages.

Comment: but my bot is admin. Sorry, it is admin of a group, not channel

Comment: @RobertoJunior Unfortunately, still can't see messages from other bots :(